# Solving a system of equations when multiple expressions are not defined

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve this system of equations for $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_3$, and $F_4$ (in terms of the $C$ quantities):

[image: system]

I enter this:

```
Solve[
 C0 == F2 + (F1 + F3)/2 &&
  C1 == (-F1 + 3 F3)/2 &&
  C2 == -F2 + 4 F4 &&
  C3 == -2 F3 &&
  C4 == -4 F4 &&
  C5 == 0,
 {F1, F2, F3, F4}]
```

However, Mathematica gives only an empty set as output.  I think this might be because there are multiple solutions?  But how can I find at least some of the solutions?

Comment: `red = Reduce[C0 == F2 + (F1 + F3)/2 && C1 == (-F1 + 3 F3)/2 && 
  C2 == -F2 + 4 F4 && C3 == -2 F3 && C4 == -4 F4 && C5 == 0, {F1, F2, 
  F3, F4}] `  yields  `C5 == 0 && C0 == -C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 && F1 == -2 C1 - (3 C3)/2 && 
 F2 == -C2 - C4 && F3 == -(C3/2) && F4 == -(C4/4) ` . Then do `Solve[red, {F1, F2, F3, F4, C5, C0}] `

Comment: Solve has 5 eqns but only has `{F1, F2, F3, F4}` , so add a var, for example, `C0` would do the job. `Solve[C0 == F2 + (F1 + F3)/2 && C1 == (-F1 + 3 F3)/2 && 
C2 == -F2 + 4 F4 && C3 == -2 F3 && C4 == -4 F4, {F1, F2, F3, F4,  C0}]`